# Add onclick function to text tag element

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML I have text in text tag:

```
<text id="aaa" > text</text>
```

Is it possible to add onclick event to this ?

Tried

```
var a = document.getElementById('aaa'); 
a.elemm.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert('blah');}, false);
```

Comment: your code is working fine just remove the a.elemm part a. itself will work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! Just change `a.elemm.addEventListener` to `a.addEventListener` :

```js
var a = document.getElementById('aaa'); 
a.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert('blah');}, false);
```

```html
<text id="aaa"> text</text>
```

Comment: OOOPS! haven't noticed that problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var a = document.getElementById('aaa'); 
a.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert('blah');}, false);
```

You just have a little mistake

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this.

```
<text id="aaa" > text</text>

var a = document.getElementById('aaa'); 
a.addEventListener('click', function(){ alert('Text has been changes');}, false);
```